# Do we want community ads for other beta sites?

Tags: discussion

What do you think about the idea to have [Community Promotion Ads](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) on our site, similar to other SE sites like [Skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/community-promotion-ads-2015) have.

Here are few advert examples:

- [Mythology Q&A proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307/mythology) which can gain more people interested in mythology (e.g. [Buddhist mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_mythology)).

  [Mythology Q&A proposal http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/58307.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307/mythology)
- [Health Q&A proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health) which can gain more people interested in health (e.g. a buddhist perspective on health, Chinese medicine, herbs, etc.).

  [Health Q&A proposal http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/66048.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health)
- [Paranormal Q&A proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96086/paranormal) for buddhists interested in practical meditation, spirituality, Chi energy, Qigong, Feng shui and ESP abilities.

  [Paranormal Q&A proposal http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/96086.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96086/paranormal)

Related:

- [How do we get Community Promotion Ads on beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248214/how-do-we-get-community-promotion-ads-on-beta-sites)

Comment: [How do we get Community Promotion Ads on beta sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248214/139866)

Comment: I think that on Buddhism.SE you see ads for other StackExchange sites, is that right? In contrast, see for example [this post about community ads](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/community-promotion-ads-2015) on Meta-Skeptics.SE (which is a graduated site): those are ads for non-StackExchange web sites. So, are there non-StackExchange web sites which you'd like to advertise on Buddhism.SE ... for example, do you want to create community ads for "Access to Insight" and/or other useful-to-Buddhism sites like that?

Comment: Well if [this answer is true](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248216/139866) (and maybe @abby can confirm whether it's true), perhaps you could change the topic title to "Do we want community ads?", and post an answer of your own in which you suggest one or more ads, and see whether the community supports (up-votes) your answer and/or posts answers of their own.

Comment: I added three community wiki answers, so that people can easily upvote ad/or down-vote one or more of them.

Comment: @chrisw: that answer is off the mark, unfortunately. (We're clarifying it over there, too.) Community promotional ads are a graduated site privilege unless there are extenuating circumstances.

Comment: @abbyhairboat Thanks for your clarification. You could close this topic as 'status-declined' then, or 'status-deferred' or whatever.

Comment: @abbyhairboat Why it's off the mark? I couldn't find any clarification on the provided links.

Comment: @kenorb see [shog's recent comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248214/how-do-we-get-community-promotion-ads-on-beta-sites/248216#comment816265_248216), and the one Anna left on that question.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes** I want community ads, but for **non-StackExchange sites** that are **useful/specific to Buddhism** (for example, for sites like '[Access to Insight](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/)' and/or other sites to be determined later).

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** I want community ads for **other new beta sites**, like the ones you proposed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**No** I do not want community ads: especially no ads for sites which are **not solely related to Buddhism**.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, I don't want **any ads** because they distract my focus, my attention and my mindfulness from that for what I'm here.